# How to write API documentation for constructors in Java

Tags: java, api, class-constructors

Do I have to write param and return tags for constructors in Java for API documentation?

This is the code I have:

```
/**
* Another constructor for class Time1
*/
public Time1 (Time1 other) 
    {
        _hour = other._hour; _minute = other._minute; _second = other._second;
    }
```

Comment: You don't "have to" do that any more than for any other public method, meaning that yeah, you should, otherwise your API documentation is incomplete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole purpose of creating a `Documentation` is for its *implementors* to be able to understand what you intended to do in your code.

- Should you create `documentation`for everything ?  **yes**
  The programmers who plan to use your `API` might not understand the "obvious" purpose of a `method,property,constructor,class` so, yes, do it even if it is obvious (It might be obvious just to you).

Using `@param, @return` `annotations` should be used only when this **is** the case, in your question code example you have:

```
/**
* Another constructor for class Time1
*/ public Time1 (Time1 other) 
    {
        _hour = other._hour; _minute = other._minute; _second = other._second;
    }
```

So, does your constructor return something ? no, so why use the `@return` annotation.
But  what your  `constructor` **does** have is a parameter, so the correct thing to  do here would be:

```
/**
* Another constructor for class Time1
* @param other  <and explain its purpose>
*/
public Time1 (Time1 other) 
    {
        _hour = other._hour; _minute = other._minute; _second = other._second;
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I would need a @return tag due to the constructor does return a new object.

Comment: The description of your constructor specifies this, but since the constructor doesn't use the **reserved word** `return` then  `@return` is not to be used.

Comment: *Should you create documentationfor everything ? yes* Not always... You shouldn't provide docs for getters/setters unless they are really useful.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make sense to include a return tag for a constructor but other than that, the constructor Javadoc is like any method's Javadoc. You don't *have* to include a particular tag but you *might* choose to for various reasons - possibly to elucidate a point about the particular parameter, to highlight under what conditions a particular exception might be thrown, or even just to comply with some in-house coding guidelines.

It's generally a good idea only to include useful information in Javadoc. Something like `Another constructor for class Time1` isn't particularly helpful - it doesn't describe why that constructor might be used over another constructor or why this constructor exists.